# Search a string before a \n but ignoring any escape characters in beginning of string (\n or \t or \r) using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that returns me a string before the first occurrence of \n ignoring escape sequence at the beginning of the string.
I am using
"([^\n])+"  regex which works fine if the strings are as below

1. "Excel Sheet for A and A Plants \nPoint" return "Excel Sheet for A and A Plants"
2. "\n\nMutiple Sheet for Data for materials\n and Services" returns "Mutiple Sheet for Data for materials"

But it starts failing if there are other escape characters in the beginning like \t or \r
eg "\t\n\tTransportation and Railways\n\t\n\n\t\n\tDocument." returns "t" and expected is "Transportation and Railways"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Capture groups let you include important context surrounding the content you want to extract. Here we use a named capture group `(?<content>)`. The character class before it `[\t\r\n]*` absorbs all `\t`, `\r`, and `\n` characters preceding `content`.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[\t\r\n]*(?<content>[^\n]+)");
var match = regex.Match(str);
if (match.Success) {
    var content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Spencer. This is what i was looking for